# How to restrict volume output in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, restrictions, volume-mixer

I have my computer hooked to a stereo which doesn't like too much volume. I like the ability to control the volume from the Windows volume control rather than the stereo, but there's a point at about 80% where it's too much for the stereo. I have to always be careful not to exceed a certain level.

How can I restrict the master volume put out of my computer beyond the standard Windows volume control? Even if it means installing a third-party program to do so?

Comment: how is it hooked to the stereo?  1/8" jack (headphone wire), optical, SPDIF?

Comment: Just a standard 1/8" jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy and cheap solution.  Get a headphone splitter with built in volume knobs.  Like [this](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=108&cp_id=10823&cs_id=1082703&p_id=7116&seq=1&format=1#largeimage).  Just lower the volume to about 80%.  This means at 100% output from your PC, the stereo will only get 80%.

Comment: I'm sure this would work no doubt, but I was looking for a software-based control without purchasing hardware.

Comment: Hmmm... I havent seen any software that does this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the volume mixer that is part of Windows 7. If you right-click on the speaker icon, select  "Open Volume Mixer". A window will open showing you your sound levels for the the system device and all applications you have open. If for example you use VLC to listen to your audio files of movies, you can set the volume for that program to 80% of your master volume and it will dynamically adjust as you set the master volume. Just be sure to open the program so that you can set the levels in the mixer. Next time you go in, the levels are remembered.

Comment: I know all about the standard windows volume control. I'm looking for a deeper setting in Windows so that when the master volume is 100% it feeds an output of 80% for example, and not one application at a time.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no deeper setting. There might be another [third party] software solution but none that I am aware of. The mixer is your best (i.g., free, already part of the system, does what you are asking it do) software solution and as others have pointed out, you could go with a hardware solution instead.